# multiple conditional style using string

Tags: react-native

I would like change style if the state is equal to the string mentionned.

like ( I think this code is not correct )

```html
<View style={this.state.style="superman" ? styles.superman || this.state.style="wonderman" ? style.wonderwoman ||
    this.state.style="flash" ? styles.flash }>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
superman: {
backgroundColor: 'red',
},
wonderwoman: {
backgroundColor: 'blue',
},
flash: {
backgroundColor: 'yellow',
},
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand , you're trying to use  [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

so for your case the code should be like this example:

```
    style={selectedHero == 'superman'/* If the hero is superman */? 
        styles.superman 
        :selectedHero == 'wonderwoman' /*Else If the hero is wonderwoman */? 
        styles.wonderWoman 
        :/* Else */ styles.flash}
```

And here is a full example on [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/dynamic-styles)